# websphere 7.0 create message engine

Tags: java, websphere, messaging

What is the Process of creating a Messaging Engine on a BUS in WebSphere 7.0.  I have a bus but there is no option to create the message and I have no idea what to do to create it or have it auto-generate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go the `Service Integration > Buses > Bus Member` panel add your server as new member. This will associate the messaging engine to the Bus. There is a wizard to help you configure it step by step.

After that you will have to create queues and topics. You could then connect to those queues and topics to send and receive messages. Personaly I use [HermesJMS](http://www.hermesjms.com/confluence/display/HJMS/Home) to test my JMS broker.